# During particle-antiparticle annihilation, are the photons expelled perfectly perpendicular?

Tags: photons, momentum, conservation-laws, quantum-electrodynamics, antimatter

During particle-antiparticle annihilation, are the photons expelled perfectly perpendicular to the original direction of the particle-antiparticle pair?

There is very little information on the web about this topic, though I read a book awhile ago that stated that the photons are emitted from an angle, not perfectly perpendicular to the particles. Is this true? If so why?

Comment: Remember that the energy and momentum of the process need to be conserved.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Yes, but this doesnt explain why they are emitted at an angle.

Comment: Maybe you can write down some equations and show your working.

Comment: Do the particle and antiparticle have definite trajectories before they annihilate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> During particle-antiparticle annihilation, are the photons expelled perfectly perpendicular to the original direction of the particle-antiparticle pair?

No.

In the center-of-momentum frame, the two photons can come out back-to-back in various directions, with a probability distribution. *Any* direction is consistent with energy-momentum conservation.

When non-relativistic electrons and positrons annihilate, all directions are equally likely for the photons; the differential cross section is *isotropic*. When the electron and positron are ultra-relativistic, the photons strongly tend to be along the direction of motion the annihilating particles. (This is for unpolarized beams.)

The calculation of the differential cross section for any energy may be found [here](http://bolvan.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/Classes/2011f/annihilation.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much for the inciteful response!